# Why are my bootstrap cards not displaying next to eachother?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-4

I have the following code defining two bootstrap cards:

```
<div id="detailPanel" class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div>
                        Detail
                        @if (@Model.ProjectId != default(int))
                        {
                            <text>- Project #</text>
                            @Model.ProjectId
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @*Custom fields*@
                    <div class="editor-label">@*Custom fields*@</div>
                    <div class="editor-field wide-editor">
                        @*Custom fields*@
                        <button id="showChooser" class="icon-button-sm">
                            <span class="fas fa-search"></span>
                        </button> <span id="description"></span>
                        @*Custom fields*@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p>Financials</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                   @*Custom fields*@
                    <div id="purchPanel">
                        @*Custom field*@
                        <div id="realEstatePanel">
                            @*Custom fields*@
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, "Purchase Price")</div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchasePrice)
                            <button id="realEstateToggle" class="k-button"></button>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchasePrice)
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="refiPanel">@Html.EditorEntryFor(model => model.RefinanceAmount, "")</div>
                    <div class="editor-field" id="equityAssetPanel">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EquityAssetId)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EquityAssetId)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what the page is displaying as currently:[image: current]
To goal is to make them side by side. Something like the example found on the official docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - replace `card` and `col-lg-6`, the last one should be parent. Second - cover `col-lg-6` in `row`. Check my example below.

This example from the Bootstrap docs illustrates it wary well https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#using-grid-markup

```
<div id="detailPanel" class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div>
                        Detail
                        @if (@Model.ProjectId != default(int))
                        {
                            <text>- Project #</text>
                            @Model.ProjectId
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @*Custom fields*@
                    <div class="editor-label">@*Custom fields*@</div>
                    <div class="editor-field wide-editor">
                        @*Custom fields*@
                        <button id="showChooser" class="icon-button-sm">
                            <span class="fas fa-search"></span>
                        </button> <span id="description"></span>
                        @*Custom fields*@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p>Financials</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                   @*Custom fields*@
                    <div id="purchPanel">
                        @*Custom field*@
                        <div id="realEstatePanel">
                            @*Custom fields*@
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, "Purchase Price")</div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchasePrice)
                            <button id="realEstateToggle" class="k-button"></button>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchasePrice)
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="refiPanel">@Html.EditorEntryFor(model => model.RefinanceAmount, "")</div>
                    <div class="editor-field" id="equityAssetPanel">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EquityAssetId)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EquityAssetId)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you try it? Did it helped?

Comment: Worked like a charm!